# Snakemake: expand params

Tags: parameters, expand, snakemake

I am trying to build a simple workflow to feed a list of parameters to a script. To illustrate:

```
SAMPLES=['A','B']

rule test:
    params:
        sample=expand("{sample}", sample=SAMPLES)
    script:
        "test.py {params.sample}"
```

However, snakemake only executes the script with sample `A`, not `B`. In other words, I believe it is executing `python test.py A B`, not `python test.py A` and then `python test.py B`. Similarly, I think this is illustrated by:

```
SAMPLES=['A','B']

rule print_samples:
    params:
        sample=expand("{sample}", sample=SAMPLES)
    script:
        "echo {params.sample} \n"
```

I would expect to see `A` and `B` printed out on separate lines, but instead it prints `A B` on the same line.

Am I missing something about the way expand works with params? Ideally I would like to add the `-j` flag to run them in parallel (at the moment `-j` simply executes with `A` alone).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the expected output.  Expand in this case is just a wrapper for

```py
[str(sample) for sample in SAMPLES]
```

which when input to the shell or script becomes the items joined with a space in between `A B`.

Instead, you want a general rule which will work for any sample (you also need an output file):

```py
rule test:
   output: "{sample}.out"
   shell:
      "test.py {wildcards.sample}"  # no need for params, assume this writes output {sample}.out
```

Here test.py is an executable.
So when you ask for A.out, `test.py A` runs, for B.out you get `test.py B`.

Next you have to ask for the outputs you want.  This is usually the first rule in the snakefile, and called all:

```py
rule all:
   input: expand('{sample}.out', sample=SAMPLES)
```

Again, expand will give you a list of samples, and in your case, rule all becomes:

```
rule all:
   input: 'A.out', 'B.out'
```

With the output files specified, snakemake determines the rule test needs to be run twice, once with A and once with B.

So remember, write your rules as a generalization for any *one* sample.  You may only need one expand in the rule all to specialize your rules for every sample.  Snakemake is responsible for figuring out what needs to be run and if you give it additional cores it can do so simultaneously for separate jobs.

Comment: Thanks, this clears a lot of things up for me! However, when I run your code (I also added quotes around `output: "{sample}.out"`), I get the following error: `The name 'wildcards' is unknown in this context. Please make sure that you defined that variable. Also note that braces not used for variable access have to be escaped by repeating them, i.e. {{print $1}}` Any thoughts?

Comment: Another piece of information: I only get this error when I use `script:`. If I do this: `shell: "python test.py {wildcards.sample}"` it works fine.

Comment: I never used the `script` directive. I use `shell` or `run`. It seems `script` is only supposed to take the path to a script, without command-line arguments. The script will, internally, access to things via a `snakemake` variable: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#external-scripts

Comment: You are both correct!  Sorry, I was copying the original question; I also usually use shell.  Edited to fix both typos and explained the python script more.